# What are the possible values of Status in Invoice that I have to handle in QuickBooks online?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Subject says it all.

I am aware that there is no API to get **status** of **Invoice** in Quickbooks online.
I have handled a few cases using due date and balance columns.

1. *Open* if not paid.
2. *Paid* if ***balance*** is 0.
3. *Overdue* if ***due date*** is less
   then the current date.

What other cases (with calculation logic) I have to handle?

Comment: You can have Partial if Balance > 0 and < TotalAmount

Comment: @sheavens : Thanks. Is there any other status?

Comment: Theres one more status called void. If TotalAmount and Balance both = 0.